# Cannot import 'ast': Flask installation on Angstrom (Beaglebone black)

Tags: python, flask, beagleboneblack, angstrom-linux

While trying to install Flask on my beaglebone black (Cloud9 GNOME Image 2013.09.04), it is encountering an ImportError for the module `ast` (installing Werkzeug module). I have Python `2.7.3` version, so this builtin shouldn't already be there?

Here are the logs:

```
Downloading/unpacking Flask
  Downloading Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz (544kB): 544kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Flask

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_themes/.git'
Downloading/unpacking Werkzeug>=0.7 (from Flask)
  Downloading Werkzeug-0.11.2.tar.gz (1.2MB): 1.2MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Werkzeug
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-root/Werkzeug/setup.py", line 56, in <module>
        import ast
    ImportError: No module named ast
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/Werkzeug/setup.py", line 56, in <module>

    import ast

ImportError: No module named ast
```

I tried importing `ast` in a regular on this board and am unable to do so. Most likely it isn't there at all, but my python and python-dev are reported as up-to-date.

Help!

Comment: Can you provide more information about your python interpreter? Show prompt from REPL.

Comment: Err, is this what you meant by REPL?

`root@beaglebone:~# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul  3 2013, 18:32:36) 
[GCC 4.7.3 20130205 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ast
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ast
>>>`

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. It seems like you have a special incomplete version of python in your linux distro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angstrom BeagleBone images had a weird, somewhat broken build of Python 2.7 IIRC, and are they are no longer supported by BeagleBoard.org. You should really upgrade to one of the current Debian images that are maintained and supported by BeagleBoard.org (http://beagleboard.org/latest-images) - I've used flask on those without any trouble.